# QGIS does not show WFS-T layer geometries

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, wfs

I am trying to add a layer from WFS-T-connection. The layer contains features with area geometries and features without geometries (geometry = NULL).

Although the layer contains geometries, QGIS shows the layer as a table only. I have been able to bypass this with other layers from the same WFS service by adding the below query, but for this particular layer, it does not seem to work.

```
SELECT * FROM <layer> WHERE <geometrycolumn> IS NOT NULL
```

Any ideas on how to get the layer to work with QGIS?

I have tested this with QGIS 3.16 and QGIS 3.20.

**Layer with and without query:**

[image: QGIS-layer panel with]

Edit: added information that the connection is WFS-T

Comment: Please provide the service address.

Comment: I am unable to provide the address, as it requires authentication.

Comment: Can you not copy-paste the plain text of the WFS adress?

Comment: can you add a describefeaturetype output for the feature in question

Comment: Are you dealing with a service that delivers some complex (application schema) data?

Comment: Yes, the application schema is complex. Geometries are not complex, but some of the attributes are. I am able to show and edit geometries from different layers from the same WFS service.